# Where is Umbraco.config stored in Azure cloud services?

Tags: azure, umbraco

I've got an existing Umbraco install on Azure cloud services (not Azure web sites), and although the web.config tells me that it should be found at ~/App_Data/umbraco.config, it isn't there.

Does anyone know where this would be stored? Is there a chance it is writing to a db table perhaps?

I need to edit some nodes as I suspect that at least one is owned by a user which no longer exists, hence no nodes at that level are visible in the admin system (JS error).

The site was set up with Umbraco Azure Accelerator, if that offers any clues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth noting that Umbraco hasn't needed the Umbraco Accelerator for Azure in the latest versions due to the use of [Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/). I am wondering which version of Umbraco you are running?  The Accelerator projects are being deprecated and have ceased  updates, as you can see [here](http://azureaccelerators.codeplex.com/wikipage/history) by the lack of recent updates.  You can read more about the reasoning behind this, and about how the Accelerator's functionality is now a part of the Azure core itself, over [here](http://ntotten.com/2012/06/21/update-on-the-windows-azure-accelerators/).

So - assuming that your site is an old one and you cannot just reinstall it as an Azure Web Site, can you firstly please confirm that you have the config enabled through the following setting in /config/umbracoSettings.config?

```
<XmlCacheEnabled>True</XmlCacheEnabled>
```

If this is false (as is best during all hosting environments except live) then we know that Umbraco will not use the cache.  Can you please also check that the following section doesn't list any other machine IP addresses in umbracoSettings.config?  Note that this is only relevant if the enabled attribute is true as in the example below.

```
<distributedCall enabled="true">
    <user>0</user>
    <servers>
        ...
    </servers>
</distributedCall>
```

Next, we need to check that Umbraco is still set to use the location /App_Data/umbraco.config through the web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="umbracoContentXML" value="~/App_Data/umbraco.config" />
</appSettings>
```

We should consider the way that Umbraco works on Azure and whether it could have any effect on your site.  The Umbraco Accelerator used to be necessary to synchronise the umbraco.config file between Azure instances. With each instance running a separate Umbraco website, there has to be a way that they can talk to each other. The accelerator mirrors that cache file between instances.

Assuming that your code is a default install, and not having been worked on by someone else before you, then it could be an idea to reduce your site to a single instance. Now see if it generates the cache after restarting the website. Finally, you can upgrade the site to see if it regenerates the cache.

These issues are usually always caused by some kind of configuration issue. I also remember that you can simulate Azure deployment using the [Windows Azure SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg433055.aspx) which you can use to examine for signs of the cache. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Umbraco Accelerator or a non Web Site project, but we currently are running Umbraco on an Azure web site and App_Data\umbraco.config comes and goes when it pleases and the website unexplainably works. I would like to find the reason behind this if anyone has an answer??

Comment: It's deleted when the site is republished. So for example if you right click on the actual node entitled Content in the content tree, and click "republish entire site" then Umbraco.config will be regenerated from scratch. Same thing happens when the worker process restarts.